# Запись приём без повторений в django

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт парикмахерской. Я хочу, для начала, сделать так, что бы у меня была одна запись в день, но я не совсем понимаю, как это сделать.
В views.py  у меня

```
def landing(request, id):
  master = get_object_or_404(Master, id=id)
  if request.method=="POST":
      form=SubscriberForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          data = form.save(commit=False)
          landing.master = master
          data.save()
          return redirect('master', id=master.id)
  else:
      form=SubscriberForm()
  return render(request, 'landing/landing.html', {'form': form})
```

вот класс в models.py

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время',default=timezone.now)
```

Подскажите, что делать дальше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переписать метод сохранения объекта добавив к нему проверку нужных параметров:

```py
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время', default=timezone.now)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        q = Subscriber.objects.filter(
            date__year=self.date.year,
            date__month=self.date.month,
            date__day=self.date.day
        )
        if q.exists() > 0:
            raise ValueError('Cannot create new event on the same date!')
        else:
            super(Subscriber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ошибку в таком случае стоит ловить и адекватно обрабатывать.

Comment: А что вместо ValueError нужно добавить, чтобы в случае ошибки был переход/переадресация на другую страницу. Я пытался с помощью redirect и render, но у меня не вышло.

Comment: Т. е. чтобы не ошибку выводило, а писалось " дата занята, выберете другую"

Comment: @KnMO Это делается как раз с помощью redirect (для переадресации) и render (для отображения какой-то своей HTML инфы), но это должно возвращаться как результат в функции View. Также, это зависит от того, как отправляется запрос на сервер – если через JavaScript, то те варианты не подходят, ответ должен быть понятным для JS, а уже в нём надо отображать ответ для пользователя и предлагать выбрать другую дату.

Comment: Нет у меня не через JS. А вот этот класс save я должен только в models делать или как-нибудь можно его во views сделать?